# Using the environment variable crashes the nodejs app

Tags: node.js, mongoose, environment-variables

The app runs on a shared server at namecheap. When I hardcode the env variable as a regular variable inside `server.js` like `let MONGO_URL=blablabla` the app works OK.

When i use `process.env.MONGO_URL` instead, it crashes. Any ideas why it is happening?

note: I have my env variable installed on node console of cpanel.

note2: The problem is not MONGO_URL, using `process.env.PORT` crashes the app too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

Added to the server.js

```js
if (process.env.NODE_ENV != 'production') {
    require('dotenv').config(); 
  }
```

And switched the app mode to "production". Now `process.env` works.

Comment: If the solution uses `dotenv`, then you should probably have mentioned that your environment variables are in a `.env` file in the question.

Comment: When I run my app on local yeah the env variables were stored in a `.env` file.

Comment: it is not working for me ? any views

Answer (score 0):

is there `process.env.MONGO_URL` in list of variable that you installed on node console of cpanel?

if it is not, put it on that list and try again

Comment: I add it as MONGO_URL to the list of cpanel/console am i doing it wrong?